# Adding Loop Feature To HTML5 Video Streaming Link

Tags: url, video-streaming, html5-video

At work we given a link to a video in our network to use for HTML5 video streaming that plays an mp4 video. Is there a way to add a string to that link that will loop the video or refresh the link at video's end. Below is a made up link but if that were real, can any extension be added to that that would work? Additionally, is having the video open muted or unmuted an option to add to the link as well or are these options something that have to be done in code through JavaScript or something like that?

https://www.examplelink.com/video/stream/12345.mp4

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

you can use the loop feature,

```
<video src="https://www.examplelink.com/video/stream/12345.mp4" type="video/mp4" autoplay loop> </video>
```

If you want to see an example of documentation, [click here](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/).